# Max real space in a varbinary(max) in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, varbinary

I am saving files (any type ) in a SQL table, using a `varbinary(max)`, I find out that the max usage of this datatype is 8000, but what does the 8000 mean?

The online documentation says that is 8000 bytes.  Does that mean that the maximum size of the file to be save there is 8000/1024 = 7.8125 KB?

I start testing and the maximum file that I can store is 29.9 MB.  If I choose a larger file a get a SQLException.

> String or binary data would be truncated. The statement has been
>   terminated.

Comment: This statement is just **plain wrong** - the capacity of a `VARBINARY(MAX)` field is **2 GB** (2'147'483'647 bytes) - not just 8000......

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Implement SQL Server 2012 (codename Denali) when it's released - it has `FileTable` feature :)

- `varbinary(8000)` is limited by 8000 bytes - that's for sure!
- `varbinary(max)` is limited by 2 gigabytes
- `varbinary(max) FILESTREAM` is limited by your file system (FAT32 - 2 Gb, NTFS - 16 exabytes)

Comment: I found the error ... based on your comments I realize that I had in my code a Archivo.Size = 8000 (Archivo is an SqlParameter), I thought that 8000 = Max ... !!!! , when I deleted this, it worked !! thanks a lot ...

Comment: useful answer !

Answer (score 10):

Taken from here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188362.aspx:

> max indicates that the maximum storage size is 2³¹-1 bytes

which is 2 147 483 647 bytes. I'm not sure why it stops at 29.9MB.

Comment: Beat you to it on that link but somehow didn't get the same reputation. ^^  Anyway, to clarify Mike's point, 2,147,483,647 bytes is 2GB, so excluding any timeout issues, that should be the maximum size of files before any truncation warnings.

Comment: Yep, that's is exactly the same info I found, but for some reason it sends the exception exactly at 29.999 MB, I wasn't expecting to upload files of 2GB but niether expected 30 MB.  Any other thougths of why am i getting this?, I alreadey changed the IIS parameters ... Thanks !!

Answer (score 5):

What version of SQL Server are you using?

[Varbinary on MSDN for SQL Server 2008](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188362.aspx) explicitly says that VarBinary(MAX) is for use when "the column data entries ***exceed*** 8,000 bytes."

Also, I would also take a look at the [Filestream Capabilities in SQL Server 2008](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933993.aspx) if that is the server you are using.

Answer (score 5):

I got the "String or binary data would be truncated" error when trying to store 5MB using varbinary(max) on SQL Server 2005. Increasing the autogrowth size for the database solved the problem. Took me a while to figure out, so just thought I'd share :)

Comment: I am running into a similar issue: using SQL Server Express 10.0.0.2531 I cannot store a 2 MB file to the database. Column type is varbinary(max), auto growth is enabled, I even increased the starting size and now I have 800 MB free space in the DB. Still I get the truncation error. I am at a loss...

Comment: @uceumern Did you find a solution?