# save fastreport template in DB

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, stream, fastreport

I followed this articel [store fast report template](http://bytes.com/topic/net/insights/891986-how-store-fastreport-net-report-templates-database) , to implement it but I cant save and load the report because the stream is empty !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I figure out the problem , it is related to the SQLSERVER real available space to store in DB for varbinary field as my FASTREPORT template size was byte[616054] so it just save 50 byte in sql , check this link [varbinarymax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5723698/max-real-space-in-a-varbinarymax-in-sql-server),
So , I changed the data type to the ntext and convert stream to string for storing and do the reverse for retrieve mechanism

this command byte to string

```
 byte[] blob = stream.ToArray();
  string st=  System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(blob);
```

and this one for retrieve

```
byte blob2 =Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(this.TableAdapter.GetDataByID(key).Rows[0]["Report"].ToString());
```

also can try this one to use varbinary(max) check it out :
[Enable File Stream in SQL](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645923%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)